# JS: insert a line break into copied text

Tags: javascript, buffer, clipboard

I'm trying to implement copying text with line brakes to the clipboard and then to paste it into a simple text file under Windows:

```
function copyText(name, value){
    var text = name + ': ' + value + '\r\n';
    var text += 'next line';
    if (document.body.createTextRange){
        var cont = document.createElement('p');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        cont.appendChild(textNode);
        document.body.appendChild(cont);
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(cont);
        textRange.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(cont);
    }
}
```

but after inserting in the file there is no line breaks. how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works:

```
var cont = document.createElement('pre');
```

Comment: it was simply easy =)